# Is there a way to merge different path to the same Control block?

Tags: uml, plantuml, activity-diagram, puml

There are only **two** targeting block which is `s1` and `s2`,but they come from different divergent path through many `condtions`,like:
[image: different path sink into s1,s2]

`source code` :

```
@startuml
!pragma useVerticalIf on

:do sth1;

if (cond1) then
    if (cond2) then 
        :s1;
    else
        :s2;
    endif
else
    if (cond3) then
        :s2;
    else
        :s1;

endif

@enduml
```

I have tried use `label` and `goto` ,but it didn't works.

How to make the arrow point to the same `s1` or `s2` rather than a copy of them?